# how to run SELENIUM project in c# as task in task scheduler

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I have built a Selenium project in C# and would like to run it every day as a task in task scheduler.
I would like to know how to make the project exec file or how to do it effectively.

Answer (score 0):

*You can schedule the task by doing the following*

**Required Tools**

```
1. NUnit3 Console. Location: https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Console-Command-Line.html

2. Windows Task Scheduler

 Download NUnit.Console-*.msi file.

 Install exe file. 

Create an nunit command to run your tests:

> nunit3-console testsfile.dll

More details here: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Console-Command-Line

Next, create the scheduled task

List item

 1. Open Task Scheduler
 2. Under Actions, Click Create a Basic Task
 3. Provide a descriptive name
 4. Choose the starting date and time.
 5. Choose Start a Program as the type of action
 6. In Program/Script add nunit3-console
 7. In Arguments add testsfile.dll
 7. In Start in add nunit3 console location
 8. Click Finish.

Now it will run on the schedule you provided.
```

Comment: i got an exception error of un when trying writing nunit3-console testfile.dll
(" Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\InternalTrace.22060.log' is denied.

--UnauthorizedAccessException")
is there way to fix it?

Comment: Use IDE with admin privilege's  like Visual Studio with Administrator privileges (right click on visual studio --> run as Administrator

**OR**

You need to change your test configuration so that access to the directory is allowed. See `Test/Edit Test Run Configurations/Deployment`.

If you are trying to read or write a file in that directory, you will probably need to copy it to the directory where the test is run. Again, the Deployment tab of the test run config dialog will help you out.

Comment: Why not run Jenkins locally?